# Sistema de consulta

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho este formulário para consultar só por um período de tempo ou só pelo nome do cliente ou então para consultar por um período de tempo e um cliente específico:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <strong>Data Início:</strong> <input type="date" name="inicio" placeholder="Data Início">
    <strong>Data Fim:</strong> <input type="date" name="fim" placeholder="Data Fim">
    <strong>Utente:</strong> <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Utente">   
    <input type="submit" value="Consultar">
</form>
```

Código:

```
$inicio = $_POST['inicio']; 
$fim = $_POST['fim'];   
$nome= $_POST['nome'];

$result_cursos = "SELECT centrodb.utentes.codigoutente,
centrodb.utentes.nome,
centrodb.utentes.descricaovalencia,
centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`DataRegisto`,
centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data`,
Inicio,
Fim,
centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')) AS `Horas Consumidas`

FROM centrodb.registoFisioterapia LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes

ON centrodb.utentes.Id = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.utente

LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores

ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome WHERE centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` >= '$inicio' OR centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` <= '$fim' OR centrodb.utentes.nome LIKE '%$nome%'";

$resultado_cursos = mysqli_query($conn, $result_cursos);

$tabela3 .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';
$tabela3 .= '<table border="5">';

$tabela3 .= '<tr>';

$tabela3 .='<thead>';

$tabela3 .= '<tr>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Nº Utente</th>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Utente</th>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Valência</th>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Data Registo</th>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Data</th>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Hora Início</th>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Hora Fim</th>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Fisioterapeuta</th>';

$tabela3 .= '<th>Horas Consumidas</th>';

$tabela3 .= '</tr>';

$tabela3 .='</thead>'; 

$tabela3 .='<tbody>';

if (empty($resultado_cursos)) {
    echo "Nenhum registro encontrado.";
}

while ($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {
$tabela3 .= '<tr>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['codigoutente'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['nome'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['descricaovalencia'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['DataRegisto'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Data'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Inicio'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Fim'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Colaborador'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '<td>'.$rows_cursos['Horas Consumidas'].'</td>';

$tabela3 .= '</tr>'; 
}

$tabela3 .= '</tr>';

$tabela3 .='</tbody>'; 

$tabela3 .= '</table>';

$tabela3 .= '</div>';

echo $tabela3;

?>
```

Quando pesquiso só pela data de inicio e data de fim retorna os dados correctos, mas se pesquiso só pelo nome do cliente ou então pesquiso pelo intervalo de tempo e nome de cliente não me retorna os dados corretos, mantém os dados que estão inicialmente.

Comment: nenhuma consulta retorna valores? nem preenchendo tudo?

Comment: A consulta no mysql retorna valores...isso quer dizer que não existe problema na query, mas depois quando monto o sistema em php não funciona...Eu pretendo filtrar ou só por período de tempo, ou só pelo nome do cliente ou então fazer os dois filtros em simultâneo. Não terá nada a ver com a parte do `where`?

Comment: Tem a ver com valores nulos ne, quando vc executa o `WHERE centrodb.registoFisioterapia.'Data' >= '$inicio'`, por exemplo, mas não preencheu a data, ele não retorna nada, porque uma condição falhou

Comment: Outra coisa, esse campo `Data`, igual no exemplo que acabei de citar, precisa de aspas?

Comment: Já está a retornar, tinha um erro no while, estava `while ($rows_cursos = mysql_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {`, mas tem que ser assim `while ($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {`. Mas mesmo assim tenho o problema porque só consigo filtrar pela data, o filtro pelo nome do cliente ou pelo intervalo de tempo e nome do cliente não funcionam.

Comment: Variável `$nome`, no ultimo `OR`, foi definida onde ?

Comment: Ok, tinha aí outro erro... Já consigo filtrar individualmente, tanto pelo intervalo de tempo como pelo nome do cliente, mas ainda não consigo filtrar pelos dois em simultâneo, pelo intervalo de tempo e pelo nome do cliente

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77151/discussion-between-iniciante-and-wees-smith).

Comment: é porque se uma condição `OR` for valida, ele já vai executar essa query, para ter os 3 juntos teria que ser `AND`, verifica se todos estão preenchidos e cria outra sql com `AND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criando o condicionamento para o `$nome` relacionando com as datas:

```
$inicio = $_POST['inicio'];
$fim = $_POST['fim'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];


if((empty($inicio))||(empty($fim))&&(empty($nome))){
    $condicao = 'OR';
}else{
    $condicao = 'AND';
}

$result_cursos = "SELECT
centrodb.utentes.codigoutente,
centrodb.utentes.nome,
centrodb.utentes.descricaovalencia,
centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`DataRegisto`,
centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data`,
Inicio,
Fim,
centrodb.colaboradores.Nome AS Colaborador,
TimeDiff(TIME_FORMAT(Fim,'%H:%i'), TIME_FORMAT(Inicio,'%H:%i')) AS `Horas Consumidas`

FROM centrodb.registoFisioterapia LEFT OUTER JOIN centrodb.utentes

ON centrodb.utentes.Id = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.utente

LEFT OUTER JOIN colaboradores

ON centrodb.colaboradores.codigo = centrodb.registoFisioterapia.Nome WHERE (centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` >= '$inicio' AND centrodb.registoFisioterapia.`Data` <= '$fim') $condicao centrodb.utentes.nome LIKE '%$nome%'";
```